# Setup SQL Transaction Log backup for every 30 mins

Tags: sql-server, sql

I know how to setup a one time sql transaction log backup from SSMS, but I could not find a very detailed steps for setup this transaction log backup for every 30 mins.

How can I do this in SSMS?

I am running SQL 2012

Comment: What is MSSM?...

Comment: Sorry,  it is SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to schedule SQL backup jobs is to setup a maintenance plan. See this link for details https://www.sqlshack.com/database-back-up-task-via-sql-server-maintenance-plans/

The method is the same to create a maintenance plan for full backups and transaction log backups, you just need to select the appropriate option when going through the steps to create the maintenance plan.

Comment: Thanks, I done it with agent jobs. I will try maintenance plan, looks it has the way to delete older backups.